# Keras inserting middle layer in complex models

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I have loaded a resnet model using 
**from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50** and now I want to insert some new layers in the middle of the model.

[Removing then Inserting a New Middle Layer in a Keras Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306433/removing-then-inserting-a-new-middle-layer-in-a-keras-model)

There is a solution described in the link above, but the ResNet model also has some **Add** layers in its architecture and this is why I get the following error:

```
ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs.
```

Is there any clean way I can insert new layers in the middle or should I code the model myself from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

In Resnet there are several blocks composed of shortcut path and main path. The difficulty depends on where and how do you want to add or delete, i.e., modifying a shortpath, modifying a main path, or deleting a path.
If you insert new layers between blocks (after Add->Activation layer), it will be much easier. If you want to delete some layer, it will be easier to delete a whole block (between two Add layer).