# Adding dropout in middle of pre-trained network

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to add a Dropout layer in the middle of RestNet50 network,
here is the code I'm trying to run:

```py
base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
layers = [l for l in base_model.layers]

conv3_block4_out = base_model.get_layer('conv3_block4_out')
x = conv3_block4_out.output

add = False
for layer in layers:
    if layer.name == 'conv3_block4_out':
        add = True
        x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
        continue

    if not add:
        continue


    x = layer(x)  # This is where the error is thrown, when the layer name is 'conv4_block1_0_conv'

x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
preds = Dense(196, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=preds)
```

What I'm doing is getting the `conv3_block4_out` layer, adding the `Dropout` to it, and then just continue stacking the leftovers.

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/machine-learning/test-proj/make_model_year_model.py", line 70, in <module>
    x = layer(x)
  File "/machine-learning/test-proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 925, in __call__
    return self._functional_construction_call(inputs, args, kwargs,
  File "/machine-learning/test-proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1092, in _functional_construction_call
    input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
  File "/machine-learning/test-proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 212, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv4_block1_0_conv is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 512 but received input with shape [None, None, None, 256]
```

This error is thrown after about 5 times that I successfully stuck the layers.

From what I know, dropout layers don't affect the shape of layers, then why do I get that error?

Can someone explain the reason and maybe suggest a change to make it work?

Comment: I do not see any Dropout layer in your code, where is it?

Comment: Where is the code that adds the dropout layer? Also you appear to be detecting 'conv4_block1_1_conv': not conv3_block4_out

Comment: Sorry it was late, i forgot to add back the line with the dropout. But anyway, it still fails even without that lines that...
Im detecting `conv4_block1_1_conv` because its the next layer after `conv3_block4_out` and thats where I want to put the dropout.

Comment: Ok so i've changed the code to be more understandable, hope it makes things more clear, the problem at the end is that it fails to stack the layers

Comment: Your code would work for simple sequential models. This is more complex than in case of simple sequential Model because `conv3_block4_out` output is used by 2 layers:  'conv4_block1_1_conv' and  `conv4_block1_0_conv `. So after adding Dropout you need to somehow change the model graph so that these 2 layers take input from the newly added graph.

A more tedious alternative would be to rebuild the whole model after the inserted layer, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306433/removing-then-inserting-a-new-middle-layer-in-a-keras-model/45309508

Comment: @PoeDator But the problem happens later, about 5 or 6 layers after `conv3_block4_out`, can you say it is still related to the fact that different layers use the same output of `conv3_block4_out`?

Comment: Correct. If you look at `base_model.summary()`, you'd see that 2 blocks are connected to `conv3_block4_out`, one is immediately below, the other is 6 more levels below.

Comment: I see... Ok so that is the problem, but I dont see how https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306433/removing-then-inserting-a-new-middle-layer-in-a-keras-model/45309508 is different from what I've tried to do, the anser they gave him is pretty much the same as I'm doing, isnt it?