# Replace layers in a built keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, layer

I want to replace the BatchNormalization layers in a custo keras model with GroupNormalization ones. I have seen a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306433/removing-then-inserting-a-new-middle-layer-in-a-keras-model) but it doesn't work because I can't build my nn in sequential mode. I have tried

```
for i, layer in enumerate(model.layers): 
    if "_bn" in layer.name: 
        model.layers[i] = tfa.layers.GroupNormalization(groups=32, axis=-1, epsilon=0.00001)
```

but it doesn't do anything. Any good way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

I would not recommend doing this. What you could do is to use different model objects and then just reuse the layer objects and add new one is needed. In your second model, you just reuse the existing layers as an input for your new layers.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If I replace batch normalization at layer j, I want to use the output of layer j-1 as the input for this layer.