# Remove intermediate/middle Layer in Keras (for Models with merge-layers)

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras

I am trying to get a fine-tuned [MobileNetV3Small](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/MobileNetV3Small) running in JavaScript. Unfortunately tfjs does not support the Rescaling layer yet. That shouldn't matter too much though, since I can rescale the image beforehand. Now I would like to get rid of the Rescaling layer in the model, but am failing to do so.

1. tf.keras' model.layers.pop seems to be not working (see e.g. [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22479)).
2. So I tried to disassemble the layers, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306433/removing-then-inserting-a-new-middle-layer-in-a-keras-model), skip the rescaling layer and assemble them to a model again. Problem is, that MobileNetV3 has some skip-layers which are concatenated by Add layers with several Inputs, so I end up with:

> ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs.

Any ideas on how to solve it? Every help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the code I used for (dis)assembling:

```
#Creating the Model with the undesired layer
base = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV3Small(input_shape=(224,224,3), include_top=False, weights='imagenet', minimalistic=True)
model=keras.Model(inputs=base.input, outputs=predictions)

# Dissasemble
layers = [l for l in model.layers]

new_in = keras.Input((224,224,3))
x = new_in
#Assemble again, but Skip Layer-No1, the Rescaling Layer
for idx,l in enumerate(layers[2:]):
    l.trainable = False
    x = l(x)
results = tf.keras.Model(inputs=new_in, outputs=x)

# Results in mentioned Error
```